# Maintaining staticmethod calls if class is renamed

Tags: python, static-methods

I have a class with a static method which is called multiple times by other methods. For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        return

    @staticmethod
    def one():
        return 1

    def two(self):
        return 2 * A.one()

    def three(self):
        return 3 * A.one()
```

Method `one` is a utility function that belongs inside the class but isn't logically an attribute of the class or the class instance.

If the name of the class were to be changed from `A` to `B`, do I have to explicitly change every call to method `one` from `A.one()` to `B.one()`? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: How do I call them from other static methods that don't have `self`?

Comment: Simple solution: **just don't use static methods and make them plain, module-level functions**. Then all of these problems disappear, and you are writing more idiomatic code to boot. IOW: "utility function that belongs inside the class but isn't logically an attribute of the class or the class instance" Then why *does it belong in the class*?

Comment: most IDEs have `"Refactoring"` function so when you use name refactoring then it try to find this name in all code and rename it too. Or use in any text editor function `"Find & Replace"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pondered this question once upon a time and, while I agree that using a refactoring utility is probably the best way to go, as far as I can tell it is technically possible to achieve this behaviour in two ways:

1. Declare the method a `classmethod`.
2. Use the `__class__` attribute. *Leads to rather messy code, and may well be deemed unsafe or inefficient for reasons I am not aware of(?).*

   ```
   class A:
       def __init__(self):
           return

       @staticmethod
       def one():
           return 1

       @classmethod
       def two(cls):
           return 2 * cls.one()

       def three(self):
           return 3 * self.__class__.one()

   a = A()
   print(a.two())
   print(a.three())
   ```

Comment: FWIW, I agree that using a `classmethod` is the best workaround.